# How to copy a file in node.js?

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, import, require, hyper

I'm learning Node.js and using the Hyper Terminal and Visual Studio Code.
I want to copy a file through Hyper Terminal and notice that `const fs = require("fs");` doesn't work in CommonJS.
So I try to use the `import` like it says in Node.js docs.
This is the code:

```
import * as fs from 'fs';

fs.copyFile("file1.txt", "file2.txt", messageFunction);

function messageFunction() {
console.log("file 1 was copied");
}
```

This is what it shows on the Hyper Terminal:

```
Catarina@DESKTOP-3FEBJ01 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/HTML.CSS.JAVASCRIPT/intro-to-node
$ node index.js
file 1 was copied
```

The problem is that does not create a new file, it simply shows the `console.log`.
I also create a `package.json` and add `"type" : "module"`.

Thank you!

Comment: does `file1.txt` exist in the current directory

Comment: Yes it does, and the `file2.txt` is supposed to be the copy.

Comment: Hello @catarinasoares if you found the answer to your own question, feel free to post it as an answer! This way you can help somebody who might stumble across your question at a later time.

Comment: Thank you both!
Yes @milo526 I did that after, because I just found out that you can only edit your comment in 5 min... ups haha

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, after 2 days I found the solution... I wrote on the paste `file1.text` instead of `file1.txt`.

But I learnt that if you use `import` with the callback function you have to change the `package.json` to `"type" : "module"`, and if you use the `const` with the `return` you need to also change the `package.json` to `"type": "commonjs"`.

Hope it helps other people! Thank you :)